# SIFT detectAndCompute throws an ipp exception

Tags: c++, opencv, sift, intel-ipp

In my real time image tracking solution, whenever i am calling detectAndCompute i get an exception thrown.

The exception doesnt crash the program, and the tracking still works (on my machine) but due to the fact that it is constantly throwing the exception, I am seeing some major performance setbacks. Here is the exception:

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFF0FBEA839 in OpenCV2.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: ipp::IwException at memory location 0x0000004CB72FC5C8.
```

I tried printing the exception to get details with a try-catch clause but it didnt give me any info. Here is the line that throws this exception:

```
algo->detectAndCompute(frame, mask, keypoints2, descriptors2, false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is harmless, see for example https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/9718.

If you run your code outside of the debugger you will not see the exception printout.